# Does Resumable.js support resumable uploading for IE v11 and Windows 10 Edge?

Tags: resumablejs

There is library Resumable.js that is:

> a JavaScript library providing multiple simultaneous, stable and resumable uploads via the HTML5 File API. The library is designed to introduce fault-tolerance into the upload of large files through HTTP.

but according to Resumable.js site:

> Resumable.js does not have any external dependencies other the HTML5 File API. This is relied on for the ability to chunk files into smaller pieces. **Currently, this means that support is limited to Firefox 4+ and Chrome 11+**

Sometimes developers do not immediately update documentation. Are there any changes at the moment: **does Resumable.js support resumable uploading for IE v11 and Windows 10 Edge?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their current documentation, they support all major browsers, including Internet Explorer 10+ ([Github Resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/)):

> Resumable.js does not have any external dependencies other than the
>   HTML5 File API. This is relied on for the ability to chunk files into
>   smaller pieces. Currently, this means that support is widely available
>   in to Firefox 4+, Chrome 11+, Safari 6+ and Internet Explorer 10+.

Their documentation doesn't say anything about Opera, but it mentions that the only Resumable.js dependency is the HTML5 File API.

Here's a link to the Opera 2.8 documentation, regarding the implementation of the File API, so it should work:
[W3C File API support in Opera Presto 2.8](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/file/)